# 3D Vector normalization issue

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra, vector-graphics

I found a problem with the 3D `Vector` normalization. It seems that it happens only with some specific numbers. Every time I call a normalization function, the `Vector` gets changed.

**Example code:**

```
Vector3 v1(-0.965090453265, -0.210381150246, 0.156014174223);

std::cout.precision(15);
v1.normalize();
std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
v1.normalize();
std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
v1.normalize();
std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
v1.normalize();
std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
```

**The output:**

```
-0.965090334415436 -0.210381120443344 0.156014159321785
-0.965090453624725 -0.210381150245667 0.156014174222946
-0.965090334415436 -0.210381120443344 0.156014159321785
-0.965090453624725 -0.210381150245667 0.156014174222946
```

**The normalize function:**

```
void Vector3::normalize()
{
    if ( length() == 0 )
        return;

    Vector3 x = *this;
    float sqr = x.x * x.x + x.y * x.y + x.z * x.z;
    *this = x * (1.0f / std::sqrt(sqr));
}
```

Is this a problem with the `float` precision, or something is wrong with my code? How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: Just figured out why I couldn't reproduce the problem.**

If I change `x /= len` in my code below to `x *= ((t) 1.) / len` then I end up with exactly what you gave for `floats`, i.e. inconsistent answers beyond the first six digits (which you should not be trusting `float` for anyway):

```
-0.965090334415436 -0.210381120443344 0.156014159321785
-0.965090453624725 -0.210381150245667 0.156014174222946
-0.965090334415436 -0.210381120443344 0.156014159321785
-0.965090453624725 -0.210381150245667 0.156014174222946
-0.965090334415436 -0.210381120443344 0.156014159321785
```

As expected, `doubles` are still correct up to the 15th digit:

```
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
```

Still, the `float` result is always consistent to the first six digits.

**ORIGINAL POST:**

This seems to be "just a floating point precision issue", since single-precision floats only give you up to [6-9 decimal digits of precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). I've written code to check this and my results don't seem nearly as bad as yours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <typename t>
class Vector3
{

public:
    t x;
    t y;
    t z;

    Vector3 (t x, t y, t z) :
        x (x),
        y (y),
        z (z)
    {}

    void normalize()
    {
        t len = std::sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

        if (len != 0.)
        {
            x /= len;
            y /= len;
            z /= len;
        }
    }

    void println()
    {
        std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::cout.precision(15);

    Vector3<float> v(-0.965090453265, -0.210381150246, 0.156014174223);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        v.normalize();
        v.println();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
-0.965090334415436 -0.210381120443344 0.156014159321785
-0.965090394020081 -0.210381135344505 0.156014174222946
-0.965090394020081 -0.210381135344505 0.156014174222946
-0.965090394020081 -0.210381135344505 0.156014174222946
-0.965090394020081 -0.210381135344505 0.156014174222946
```

Changing `Vector3<float>` to `Vector3<double>` gives consistent results up to the 15th digit:

```
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
-0.965090340387771 -0.210381125639766 0.156014155975542
```

Notice that even where `float` results stopped changing, the digits are not actually correct beyond the first seven.

Comment: I've changed my normalize function to yours, and it seems to be OK for my current needs. Thanks a lot for your help! Best regards.